# How can I find where a specific font is used in my web page?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-devtools

I'm a web developer, and I can see from Chrome DevTools that Chrome is loading an italic version of one of my fonts on every page. However, I have not intentionally used italics. I cannot see any font on the page that uses italics. I'd like to find the HTML element that is triggering that font load in order to eliminate it from my template. How can I do that?

Perhaps a javascript or jQuery snippet that goes through the DOM to look at the font-style of every element?

Comment: Open devTools, select an element that have this modified font, go to tab "computed", look for `font-family` or `font-style`, hover it and probably an arrow icon will show up, click it and it will show the CSS class where the font was setted

Comment: Maybe you can find out by searching in folder with your code editor for `font-style: italic` and see which class in your css use this property, then you can find which element is using this class

Comment: @CalvinNunes - the point is I don't know where on the webpage to look. As far as I can see none of the elements have this font.

Answer (score 2):

1. You can try to look inside network tab of the google chrome dev tools, click on fonts and reload the page. You will then see all loaded fonts. In the column "Initiators" you can see who was calling that font. Sometimes plugins are loading their list of fonts, and don't use it at all. That can help you maybe.
2. If you want to glance over which fonts you are using, you can install this chrome plugin https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/whatfont/jabopobgcpjmedljpbcaablpmlmfcogm?hl=en

For more information, please provide a link for that website.

Answer (score 1):

I think you were looking for:

```
[...document.querySelectorAll('*')]
    .filter(e=>getComputedStyle(e).fontStyle === 'italic')
```

Pasting this snippet in the Developer Console will give you a list. If you expand the list, and click on individual elements, they will get selected in the Elements inspector. From there, you will also be able to tell which CSS file is giving that font style. 
This will also work for any other CSS property, if you update the code snippet.